# How do I make my Instagram account appear in someone's "Suggested for you" accounts list?

Tags: privacy, instagram, user-accounts, list

I would like to have my public Instagram account appear in someone's "**Suggested for you**" accounts list. Her Instagram account is private; she has 200 followers and follows 1000 accounts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook (IG) gives an overview of the algorithm they use to determine which accounts will be 'suggested to you' [on their website](https://transparency.fb.com/features/explaining-ranking/ig-suggested-accounts/).

> **How Instagram Suggested Accounts works**
>
> In order to make the AI system most effective, we use two recommenders that function at different times.
>
> **Recommender one**
>
> - This recommender shows suggested accounts when you’re viewing your home feed.
> - This recommender helps you discover accounts you might want to follow, based on factors such as whether or not you are new to Instagram, and similarities between your account and the suggested accounts.
>
> **Recommender two**
>
> - This recommender determines which accounts will be suggested to you after you follow a suggested account.
> - If the account you’re viewing has fewer than 1,000 followers, the system tries to find and suggest accounts from people in your social circle that are relevant to the account you’re viewing, such as your friends and family who also follow the account.
> - If the account you’re viewing has 1,000 or more followers, the system tries to find and suggest accounts that are relevant to your interests and that are similar to the account you're viewing.
>
> <sub><sup>*[Transparency: Instagram Suggested Accounts AI system](https://transparency.fb.com/features/explaining-ranking/ig-suggested-accounts/)*</sup></sub>

In short, you can game these to some extent (for example by becoming 'friends' with people in their social circle, adding their number to your telephone book and following accounts where you share a mutual interest), but it sounds pretty hit-and-miss to me.